# Trying to do a boolean loop

Tags: java, loops, boolean

I'm new to this and i wanted to try and do a loop i kinda get how to do it but I'm stuck. I'm getting these errors not really sure what to do with it though.

> Duplicate local variable minutes
>    Duplicate local variable choice
>
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to String
>   The operator /
>   is undefined for the argument type(s) String, double
>   The operator /
>   is undefined for the argument type(s) String, double
>   Type mismatch:
>   cannot convert from double to String

```
     `import java.util.Scanner;

   public class LoopTest {
   public static void main(String[] arge) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double minutes = 0;
    double minutesperday;
    double minutesperyear;
    double years;
    double days;
    double choice;

    boolean keepPlaying = true;
    while (keepPlaying) {
        String minutes;
        String choice;

        System.out.print("number of minutes");
         minutes = scanner.nextDouble();

        minutesperday = 60 * 24;
        minutesperyear = minutesperday * 365;

        years = (minutes / minutesperyear);
        days = (minutes / minutesperday) % 365;

        System.out.print(minutes + " is about" + "\nYears:" + years  + "\nDays:" + days);

        System.out.print("\nWant to enter more minutes (y/n)? ");
        choice = scanner.nextDouble();

        if (choice.equals("y")) {
            keepPlaying = true;
        } else {
            keepPlaying = false;
        }

       }

}
}
```

Comment: why do you declare minutes  `String minutes`; again?

Comment: Comment String minutes and String choice..
and your code will work fine

Comment: The error is pretty explicit...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple: as the errormessage already says:

> duplicate local variable

Which basically means that two variables with the same name exist within the same scope. In your case `double minutes` and `String minutes` and same for `choice`. Actually the `String minutes` is the one causing the other errors, since java thinks `minutes / minutesperyear` means the variable `String minutes`, not `double minutes`.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the `String choice` and the `double choice`, you can directly scan a `boolean` `true/false` and store it in `keepPlaying`
- Remove `String minutes`, because you already have a `double minutes` variable which can store the minutes
- Close the `scanner`

**Corrected code**

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double minutes = 0;
    double minutesperday;
    double minutesperyear;
    double years;
    double days;

    boolean keepPlaying = true;
    while (keepPlaying)
    {
        System.out.print("number of minutes");
        minutes = scanner.nextDouble();

        minutesperday = 60 * 24;
        minutesperyear = minutesperday * 365;

        years = (minutes / minutesperyear);
        days = (minutes / minutesperday) % 365;

        System.out.print(minutes + " is about" + "\nYears:" + years + "\nDays:" + days);

        System.out.print("\nWant to enter more minutes (true/false)? ");
        keepPlaying = scanner.nextBoolean();
    }
    scanner.close();
```